# How to maintain a cached data pool using react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-query

I want to create a custom hook that maintains a cache and fetches only new items.

Expected behavior:

If I requested `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` initially, it fetches all `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` since the cache is empty.

If I requested `[1, 2, 3]` then, it shouldn't fetch anything and returns from the cache.

If I requested `[4, 5, 6]` then, it should take 4 and 5 from the cache and fetch only 6 and add that to the cache.

How can I achieve this optimistically?

Answer (score 3):

If you're already using `react-query`, then you don't need a custom hook: it already manages this cache for you based on your [query keys](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-keys):

> At its core, React Query manages query caching for you based on query keys.

It also already provides a hook for [parallel](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/parallel-queries) (concurrent), independent queries. That hook is called [`useQueries`](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQueries):

```js
const results = useQueries({
  queries: [
    { queryKey: ['post', 1], queryFn: () => fetchPost(1) },
    { queryKey: ['post', 2], queryFn: () => fetchPost(2) },
  ],
});
```